# Count a variable during a time span by joining four tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are four tables:

```
Propertyno (
    propertyno, 
    street, 
    city, 
    postcode, 
    type, 
    rooms, 
    rent, 
    ownerno, 
    staffno, 
    branchno)

Viewing (
    clientno, 
    propertyno, 
    viewdate, 
    comment)

Client (
    clientno, 
    fname, 
    lname, 
    telno, 
    preftype, 
    maxrent)

Registration (
    clientno, 
    branchno, 
    staffno, 
    datejoined)
```

Finding the number of property views per branch within 1 month, 2 months, and 3 months of client registration requested. Since the exact database is not accessible as of now the answer to the question would be subjected to kind of interpretation and perception in the similar situation (This question can consider as a kind of abstract one). I provide a sample code according to my understanding. Since I am a beginner, certainly the below code is most probably wrong. Also, I do not have an exact idea about the counting of views during one month, 2months and so on.  I appreciate if you could correct me with your codes and comments.

```
SELECT 
   PR.propertyno, PR.branchno, V.clientno, V.propertyno, V.viwedate, 
   R.clientno, R.datejoined 
FROM 
   PropertyforRent PR LEFT JOIN Viewing V ON PR.propertyno = V.propertyno
   INNER JOIN Client AS C ON V.clientno = C.clientno
   INNER JOIN Registration AS R ON C.clientno = R.clientno
SELECT COUNT(viewdate) WHERE start_date <=@date AND end_date >=@date
   GROUP BY propertyno
   GROUP BY branch;
```

Comment: Try explaining the relationships between the tables and your desired outcome with some sample data.

Comment: When you provide your sample data, don't forget to do so in the form of DDL `CREATE` statements and `INSERT` statements: [How to post data for a T-SQL question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/). Also, make sure you post your expected output for the sample data you have provided.